# Display values in model B that belongs to A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a **Company.rb** model that **has_many :applications** what I am trying to now is to show all applications the company has created.

When a Company creates an application I store their id inside Application.rb in the column called **company_id** by using merge on #create.

What I am trying now is to make it so that I can have a page where they can see the applications they have created. How do I only show applications that match current_company.id with the company_id in the Application.rb ?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html is a great place to start for this. Or look at the getting started guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
@applications = current_company.applications
```

Then use `@applications` in your views.